# How to have an uninstall option for an MSI or set up file which was created for an application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

I created a setup for the application i created . What i need is to have an uninstall option in the start Menu where the programs are displayed and also in the folder where the application is installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure since I never tried but ...
To uninstall a MSI, from [what I read in **MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa372024), you can always run your MSI with the `/uninstall` option.

Maybe all you need is to create a link in your User Start Menu to call :

```
msiexec /uninstall package.msi
```

Here is a link where everything is explained : [Create Uninstall MSI Shortcut](http://angelorohit.blogspot.com/2009/02/creating-uninstall-shortcut-for-your.html)

Give it a try :)

Comment: Good suggestion (+1) I would recommend however to loose the "Hope this helps", a bit like in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers-for-so-questions

Comment: @VonC Ah yes, my plain old "Hope this helps" appears when I'm not sure. Ok I'm going to change my habits, thanks for editing :)

Comment: I did not know how to implement this can you please provide  some thing other

Comment: @Dorabaru : Here is a link how to create a shortcut for your MSI : http://www.ehow.com/how_7383899_create-shortcuts-msi.html . With this, you can add any shortcut to your MSI, for example an Uninstall Shortcut :)

Comment: I got struck at the second point after creating short cut can you please help

Comment: @Dorabaru : You're stuck in creating the Sortcut or having it in the right place in your project ? Well, I recognize it's not that simple, maybe this link will be clearer : http://angelorohit.blogspot.com/2009/02/creating-uninstall-shortcut-for-your.html :)